# Possible to Create Wii U Tablet Interaction?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, wii, airconsole

Its possible to create wii U tablet effects/controllers with AirConsole API? what we call **2 screens** gameplay? similar to zombie U or other games like create a mario maker? or create a area to touch/draw and add effects like create a inventory manager and then back to the controller on the smartphone?

examples:

- [Wii U New Super Mario Bros U Gameplay On Gamepad!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGBcV6cASbo)
- [Zombiu - Gamepad Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSthBI9onhE)

Answer (score 1):

You have full control over what is displayed on the big screen and on the smartphone screen and you can send any kind of data back and forth and you can have pretty much any interaction on the smartphone. So you can create any kind of multiscreen screen experience you want.

Comment: so u say that i can use anything... even videos for tutorial.. add.. dynamic content on the controller.html? so for this i think i need use html5! right? or even like zelda create inventory manager and live map.

Comment: sure. And yes everything needs to be html5